What is the Time Complexity of a function if there is an upper limit to the variable
I have the following piece of code.
void foo(int n){
  n=n*n;
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(n<10)
      cout << i;
    else
      break;
  }
}

Now I wanted to ask if the time complexity of this function is O(n^2) or O(1)?
From my point of view, the worst case is that the loop runs from 0 to 9. Meaning the worst case becomes a constant. So in my opinion, the time complexity should be O(1).

It is O(1), constant time.

I'd agree with you. As n grows from 1 to 3, the time grows quadratically, but then it stops growing, so it remains constant as n approaches infinity.

Time complexity is about how the time needed increases with larger values; once you've reached foo(10), increasing the value of the argument doesn't change the time. So it's O(1).

You're correct that it's O(1) since there are never more than 10 iterations, given any input n, but re-writing your loop end condition might make it a little more obvious: m=min(n*n, 10); for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) { cout << i; }

@wLui155 "re-writing your loop end condition might make it a little more obvious" -- Your re-write changes the functionality. (The if checks n, not i.) To make the functionality more obvious, the if should be moved outside the loop. if(n<10) { for (int i=0;i<n;i++){ cout << i; } }. For parameters larger than 3, no work is done. But I do agree that the line n=n*n; makes the code deceptive, and a different variable should be used to store n*n. Preferably one with a name longer than a single character.
